# R, dplyr split dataframe by string in columns

Tags: r

I've seen examples here that show how to split a dataframe using column index ranges but how do I split my dataframe with dplyr using strings found in the column? I've purposely created my dataframes so the columns have certain strings in them for future splitting.

Example data:

```
Site   A_Argas   A_Arachnicea   A_Brus   B_Burkoll   B_Brielle  B_Bact
 1       10        0              0         0           0         0
 2       0         0              0         10          22        123
 3       1         2              3         88          12        546
```

I want to split this dataframe up based on strings such as "A_" or "B_" and assign them to new  dataframes.

For example the output would be:

```
 dataframeA
 Site   A_Argas   A_Arachnicea   A_Brus 
 1       10        0              0        
 2       0         0              0        
 3       1         2              3       

 dataframeB
 Site   B_Burkoll   B_Brielle  B_Bact
  1       0           0         0
  2      10          22        123
  3      88          12        546
```

Because this data is not in long format, I can't seem to figure how to change my old code that I used to split the longform dataframes (for a different analysis).

```
dataframeA <- data %>% filter("GroupID" == "Arachnids") # where "A_" in column headers signify arachnid species
dataframeB <- data %>% filter("GroupID" == "Bacteria") # where all "B_" in the column headers are bacterial species
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One base R option might be to `grep` for the columns starting with `A_` and `B_`, then to subset your original data frame.

```r
a_names <- grep("^A_", names(data), value=TRUE)
dataframeA <- data[ , c("Site", a_names)]
b_names <- grep("^B_", names(data), value=TRUE)
dataframeB <- data[ , c("Site", b_names)]
```

Comment: Actually, it didn't work with my full dataframe. Not sure why because the sample I gave here is just a small snippet of it... Your solution does work with the sample set I gave. My full dataframe just has more mini strings like "V_" etc. so I don't see why this won't work

Comment: Oh I think the issue is because I decided to get rid of the "Sites" column and just shove those into my index. It worked once I just got rid of the "Site" call and just used ```data[,a_names]```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution, based on `group_split`, `pivot_longer`, `pivot_wider` and `map`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(Site = c(1, 2, 3), A_Argas = c(10, 0, 1), A_Arachnicea = c(0, 
0, 2), A_Brus = c(0, 0, 3), B_Burkoll = c(0, 10, 88), B_Brielle = c(0, 
22, 12), B_Bact = c(0, 123, 546)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>% 
  group_split(str_extract(name, "^[A-Z]\\_")) %>% 
  map(~ pivot_wider(.x, id_cols = Site))

#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>    Site A_Argas A_Arachnicea A_Brus
#>   <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1      10            0      0
#> 2     2       0            0      0
#> 3     3       1            2      3
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>    Site B_Burkoll B_Brielle B_Bact
#>   <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1     1         0         0      0
#> 2     2        10        22    123
#> 3     3        88        12    546
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `split.default` for this in `base R`, remove the first column ('Site'), `split` the data into a `list` of dataframe by removing the substring from the `_` (using `trimws`), `cbind` the first column in the `list` of data.frames and change the `list` name

```
lst1 <- split.default(data[-1], trimws(names(data)[-1], whitespace = "_.*"))

lst2 <- Map(cbind, Site = data['Site'], lst1)
names(lst2) <- paste0("dataframe", names(lst1))
```

-output

```
> lst2
$dataframeA
  Site A_Argas A_Arachnicea A_Brus
1    1      10            0      0
2    2       0            0      0
3    3       1            2      3

$dataframeB
  Site B_Burkoll B_Brielle B_Bact
1    1         0         0      0
2    2        10        22    123
3    3        88        12    546
```

It may be better to keep it in a list and access the elements as

```
lst2[["dataframeA"]]
lst2$dataframeA
```

instead of creating multiple objects (although can be created with `list2env`

```
list2env(lst2, .GlobalEnv)
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we could loop over the substring of the column names and `select` the relevant columns with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
str_remove(names(data)[-1] , "_.*") %>%
   unique %>% 
   map(~ data %>% 
   select(Site, starts_with(.x)))
```

-output

```
[[1]]
  Site A_Argas A_Arachnicea A_Brus
1    1      10            0      0
2    2       0            0      0
3    3       1            2      3

[[2]]
  Site B_Burkoll B_Brielle B_Bact
1    1         0         0      0
2    2        10        22    123
3    3        88        12    546
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Site = 1:3, A_Argas = c(10L, 0L, 1L), A_Arachnicea = c(0L, 
0L, 2L), A_Brus = c(0L, 0L, 3L), B_Burkoll = c(0L, 10L, 88L), 
    B_Brielle = c(0L, 22L, 12L), B_Bact = c(0L, 123L, 546L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```